# When VTCing as dupe, if the question you're on gets edited before you VTC, the whole question goes blank

Tags: bug, javascript, live-refresh, close-dialog

To reproduce:

- Open up the VTC as duplicate interface
- Click on an original question (this can also be done after the edit notice appears in the next step)
- Wait for the question to be edited, so that "An edit has been made to this post" appears. (You cannot make the edit yourself in a different tab, because edits that your own account makes do not result in the notice appearing). The page should look like this:

[image]

- Click anywhere inside the question (possibly on the duplicate interface)

Everything inside the question will disappear:

[image]

---

Technical details:

The problem is that the question's `.postcell` receives an opacity of 0 which never goes away:

```html
<div class="postcell post-layout--right" style="opacity: 0;">
```

The bug can be understood by looking at the following lines in realtime-se.js's `replaceIndividualPostContents`:

```js
// When a post with an edit notice is clicked,
// the following runs to replace the post with the new contents:
// $oldPost is a .question or .answer

var $oldBodyCell = $oldPost.find('.postcell, .answercell'),
    $newBodyCell = $newPost.find('.postcell, .answercell').css({ opacity: 0 });
// ...
$.when(
  fadeOut($oldBodyCell)
).then(function() {
  // ...
  $oldBodyCell.replaceWith($newBodyCell);
  // ...
  return $.when(
      fadeIn($newBodyCell)
  );
```

The `.find('.postcell, .answercell')` is meant to navigate from a parent `.question` or a `.answer` to a container on the right containing the post content, so that that container can be replaced. But what makes the duplicate interface in particular produce this bug is that, when viewing a question preview, there are *many* `.postcell, .answercell` elements inside the `$oldPost` - not only one for the question you're currently closing, but *also* one for the original question *and* one for every one of the original question's answers.

So `$oldBodyCell` contains multiple elements. `[0]` is the question cell we want, `[1]` is the question cell *in the original preview*, `[2]` is an answer cell *in the original preview*, etc. This is a problem because the  `$oldBodyCell.replaceWith($newBodyCell);` will **clone** the `$newBodyCell` when there's more than one element to be replaced. After replacing, the actual DOM element that the `$newBodyCell` contains will be the *last* element replaced:

```js
const $oldBodyCell = $('.cell');
const $newBodyCell = $('<div>replaced cell</div>');

$oldBodyCell.replaceWith($newBodyCell);
$newBodyCell.css({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' });
console.log($newBodyCell.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cell">cell 1</div>
<div class="cell">cell 2</div>
<div class="cell">cell 3</div>
<div class="cell">cell 4</div>
```

But the element which `$newBodyCell` contains will be the last answer in the *original preview*, so:

```js
fadeIn($newBodyCell)
```

fades in the wrong element; the question cell for the question the user is currently on has been replaced with a clone of `$newBodyCell` containing the updated post contents, but the `$newBodyCell` does not contain that cloned element. So, the clone doesn't get faded in, and the main question cell remains at `opacity: 0` forever.

---

To fix it, the `$oldBodyCell` should only select the main question cell, and not any of its descendants. Maybe change

```js
var $oldBodyCell = $oldPost.find('.postcell, .answercell')
```

to

```js
var $oldBodyCell = $oldPost.find('.postcell, .answercell').first()
```

That fixes the problem for me, at least.

Comment: Cross-site post on MSO: [Question blanks out if edited while looking at vote to close dialog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384427/4642212). This question could also be tagged [tag:live-refresh] and [tag:vote-to-close].